# Переименовать каталог по маске cmd

Tags: cmd, bat, строки

Нужно переименовать из bat-файла каталог (папку) из, допустим, `test-123` в, допустим, `test` по маске. Т.е `-123` неизвестно (меняется).

```
ren test* test
```

не работает

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Команда `ren` не допускает использование подстановочных символов. Задачу можно решить с помощью `for`:

```
for /d %%d in (test*.*) do (
    ren %%d test
)
```

Учтите, что этот код найдёт и попытается переименовать в `test` все каталоги, чьё имя начинается с `test` (и, в том числе, с ним совпадает). Если найденных каталогов будет много, переименуется только первый.